# Windows Terminal Autocomplete Freezes after Semicolon

Tags: autocomplete, windows-terminal

On Windows Terminal using WSL 2 + bash, if my current input ends in `;` and I hit `[TAB]`, that tab terminal becomes unresponsive to user input for about 25 seconds.  `[CTRL] + [C]` prints `^C` to the screen, `[BACKSPACE]` doesn't work, etc.  After 25 seconds, that tab becomes responsive again.  Other tabs continue to work.

This problem occurs pretty much regardless of what text precedes the semicolon.

This problem does not occur if there is any text after the semicolon or if it is a `\;`.

Autocomplete otherwise works totally fine.  Hitting `[TAB]` on a totally blank line does noting (it neither attempts to autocomplete nor freezes the terminal).

What is going on and how do I fix it?

I have confirmed this problem on the following setups:

- Windows Terminal version 1.6.10571.0 running Ubuntu 20.04
- Windows Terminal version 1.18.2822.0, running Ubuntu 22.04.03

Comment: What shell are you using? Does it happen with multiple shells or just the one? What WT version?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Version: 1.6.10571.0, using bash; I added these details to the question as well.

Comment: Thanks - I have reproduced the issue here with `bash` on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.  At least that tells us that it's not something unique to your configuration.

Comment: Further research - I *cannot* reproduce when `ssh`'d into a "pure Linux" cloud-VM with Ubuntu 20.04 and `bash` (in Windows Terminal).  Instead, I get the error bell, but no delay/freeze.

Comment: Also, sorry - Just noticing that this one is also on Stack Overflow. Like your previous question, I'd recommend moving it over to Super User since it isn't programming related.

Comment: @Zags still no solution to this? Keeps happening and not only with the ';' char but also when tabbing from a value pulled from history using Ctrl+R...

Comment: @PentaKon still happening, still no solution